# Calling php functions that have an instance as an argument

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5

Ok so my question is, i have a Facebook call back function that I'm using. The callback function uses an instance as an argument `facebookCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)`

The function works great,I'm using this in my auth controller in larvel , but now I want to reuse this function within the same controller something like `$this>facebookReusableCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb)`

I'm having issues ,i get this error `facebookReusableCallBack()` must be an instance of `SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk`, none given.

here's a sample of my code:

```
public function facebookCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
        $this->facebookReusableCallBack();
}

public function facebookReusableCallBack() {
    //All my code here
}
```

how can I reuse this function within my controller?

i've tried :

```
public function facebookCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
        $this->facebookReusableCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb);
}
```

but the argument doesn't get passed as an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define the type of a variable when you pass it in.

Method definition:

```
public function facebookReusableCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
      //some code
}
```

Execution within another method:

```
function myMethod() {
  $var = new LaravelFacebookSdk();
  $this->facebookReusableCallBack($var);
}
```

What you have done is define the type of the variable in your function definition (good) to force the type. However these are only needed in the definition.

So for your explicit example:

```
public function facebookCallBack(LaravelFacebookSdk $fb) {
   $this->facebookReusableCallBack($fb);
}
```

Because $fb must be an instance of LaravelFacebookSdk  when calling facebookCallBack it will be fine for facebookReusableCallBack.